# How to add a 3d model to android app like in Pokemon Go?

Tags: android, 3d

I'd like to know how you can achive those 3d models in your app like in Pokemon Go.

Like this: [http://images.techhive.com/images/article/2016/07/arcanine-cp-100671418-medium.pnge](http://images.techhive.com/images/article/2016/07/arcanine-cp-100671418-medium.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By using a 3D game engine like Unity? http://www.nytimes.com/2016/07/14/technology/unity-technologies-maker-of-pokemon-go-engine-swells-in-value.html?_r=0

Comment: So you can use unity with android? Well thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pokemon Go uses Unity to accomplish this.